# Multiple let declaration of the same helper method inside of an example group

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Is there a way I can declare the same helper method, using let, inside of the same example group, but let it return different values in different expectation?

It would be something like

```
describe MyClass do 
  subject(:my_obj) { described_class.new(my_var) }
  describe '#my_method' do 
    context 'some context' do 
      let(:my_var) { 0 } 
      # expectation that involves my_var 

      let(:my_var) { 1 }
      # expectation that involves my_var 
    end 
  end 
end
```

A solution would be to provide different contexts for each of the expectation, but is it possible to solve this without adding more contexts?

Comment: Make a sub-context. That's what they're for. As far as I know, the last definition sticks, and you just stomp all previous declarations if you repeat yourself. Remember, the tests don't necessarily run in any particular order, so there's no point where they could switch. The context serves as a container that makes it clear which applies.

Comment: That's what I was thinking...but I was wondering if there was another way that didn't bloat my test suite with sub contexts.

Comment: Don't think of it as bloat. Think of it as clarity. You could also create two different names, and just use different values in the second set of tests.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "two different names", could you clarify?
The problem is that I need to provide a value for the argument passed when initializing the object.

Comment: As in `let (:a) = { ... }` and `let (:b) = { ... }` where within the tests you just use the correct variable. They're your tests, you can use whatever name you want presumably. If you want the names consistent for whatever reason, sub-context is the only way.

Comment: Unfortunately the "two different names" approach does not work here. I need to provide the value for an argument passed during the object creation which is on the outermost context.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at now. Yeah, the only way is a subcontext.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the access to an example object and its metadata in the `let` block in combination with the tests metadata:

```
let(:my_var) do |example|
  example.metadata[:my_var]
end

context 'some context' do 
  it "my_var is 0", my_var: 0 do # <= here we set the necessary metadata
    ...
  end

  it "my_var is 1", my_var: 1 do # <= ... and again
    ...
  end
end
...
```

Unlike explicit sub-contexts, this way of writing specs is relatively rarely used, so it adds some mental overhead for anyone reading this code for the 1st time. But the thing is that deeply nested contexts aren't "free" either (at some nesting level it's just quite hard to understand what's going on), so flattening the spec with some "magic" might make sense - depending on the use case. Personally I'd use sub-contexts if I can and some white magic only if I must...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define an array an iterate over it, simply:

```rb
describe MyClass do 
  subject(:my_obj) { described_class.new(my_var) }
  describe '#my_method' do 
    context 'some context' do
      [0,1].each do |n|
        let(:my_var) { n } 
        # expectation that involves my_var 
      end
    end 
  end 
end
```